# Create Folder and Insert if Not Present

Tags: php

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using Aurigma's Image uploader software to allow users to upload images for locations they visit. The information is saved via the script shown below:

```
<?php

//This variable specifies relative path to the folder, where the gallery with uploaded files is located.
//Do not forget about the slash in the end of the folder name.
$galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/';

require_once 'Includes/gallery_helper.php';

require_once 'ImageUploaderPHP/UploadHandler.class.php';

/**
 * FileUploaded callback function
 * @param $uploadedFile UploadedFile
 */
function onFileUploaded($uploadedFile) {

  $packageFields = $uploadedFile->getPackage()->getPackageFields();
  $username=$packageFields["username"];
  $locationid=$packageFields["locationid"];

  global $galleryPath;

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $absThumbnailsPath = $absGalleryPath . 'Thumbnails' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

  if ($uploadedFile->getPackage()->getPackageIndex() == 0 && $uploadedFile->getIndex() == 0) {
    initGallery($absGalleryPath, $absThumbnailsPath, FALSE);
  }

  $locationfolder = $_POST['locationid'];
  $locationfolder = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.()\[\]{}]/i', '_', $locationfolder);
  if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath . $locationfolder)) {
    mkdir($absGalleryPath . $locationfolder, 0777);
  }

  $dirName = $_POST['folder'];
  $dirName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.()\[\]{}]/i', '_', $dirName);
  if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath . $dirName)) {
    mkdir($absGalleryPath . $dirName, 0777);
  }

  $path = rtrim($dirName, '/\\') . '/';

  $originalFileName = $uploadedFile->getSourceName();

  $files = $uploadedFile->getConvertedFiles();

  // save converter 1

  $sourceFileName = getSafeFileName($absGalleryPath, $originalFileName);
  $sourceFile = $files[0];
  /* @var $sourceFile ConvertedFile */
  if ($sourceFile) {
    $sourceFile->moveTo($absGalleryPath . $sourceFileName);
  }

  // save converter 2   

  $thumbnailFileName = getSafeFileName($absThumbnailsPath, $originalFileName);
  $thumbnailFile = $files[1];
  /* @var $thumbnailFile ConvertedFile */
  if ($thumbnailFile) {
    $thumbnailFile->moveTo($absThumbnailsPath . $thumbnailFileName);
  }

  //Load XML file which will keep information about files (image dimensions, description, etc).
  //XML is used solely for brevity. In real-life application most likely you will use database instead.
  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');

  //Save file info.
  $xmlFile = $descriptions->createElement('file');
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('name', $_POST['folder'] . '/' . $originalFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('source', $sourceFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('size', $uploadedFile->getSourceSize());
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('originalname', $originalFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('thumbnail', $thumbnailFileName);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('description', $uploadedFile->getDescription());
  //Add additional fields
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('username', $username);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('locationid', $locationid);
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('folder', $dirName);
  $descriptions->documentElement->appendChild($xmlFile);
  $descriptions->save($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');
}

$uh = new UploadHandler();
$uh->setFileUploadedCallback('onFileUploaded');
$uh->processRequest();
?>
```

In additon to the original script I've added code that creates a folder, with it's name based on the current 'locationid'. This is shown below.

```
  $locationfolder = $_POST['locationid'];
  $locationfolder = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.()\[\]{}]/i', '_', $locationfolder);
  if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath . $locationfolder)) {
    mkdir($absGalleryPath . $locationfolder, 0777);
  }
```

What I like to incorporate, is a check that looks to see whether there is a folder already setup with the current 'locationid' value, if not create the folder. I'm ceratianly no expert in PHP, but I know that to check to see whether a file exists, the `if(file exists....)` can be used, but I just wondered whether someone could tell me please how I can implement this check for the folder name?

Many thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [is_dir()](http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) is what you are looking for.

**UPDATE:**

The code you have:

```
if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath . $locationfolder)) {
   mkdir($absGalleryPath . $locationfolder, 0777);
}
```

Does exactly what you want. It checks for the folder and if it does not exist then it creates one for you (with CHMOD 777). Don't see what your question is then...

Comment: many thanks for the clarification. I have to admit, I wasn't 100% sure what the whole section of code actually did. Because I am relatively new to this, I did a 'copy & paste' and just changed what I thouhgt I needed to. But it's good to get some guidance from those with a lot more knowledge. Regards